# Android Studio generates R file only for modules with no module dependencies in multi-module project

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-studio-3.3

After updating to AS 3.3.1 from 3.2.something I've got a strange bug: R file is generated only for modules that do not implement any other modules. **I still can compile project or go to declaration** via cmd+B, but every resource file like `R.layout.activity_main` is highlited with an "unresolved reference" message, until I remove every module implementation from module `build.gradle` and resync the project.

As far as I've noticed, the problem does not related with android gradle 3.3.0 or kotlin 1.3, since my old projects are affected as well.

What I've already tried:

- Clean/Rebuild project
- Invalidate cache
- Resync Gradle
- Switch to Android Gradle 3.2.1
- delete `.idea` directory

Here's my [project](https://github.com/SirMeowingtons5/Android-CA-MVI-boilerplate/tree/dev), [module build.gradle example](https://github.com/SirMeowingtons5/Android-CA-MVI-boilerplate/blob/dev/sources/features/mainscreen/build.gradle.kts) and [used libraries](https://github.com/SirMeowingtons5/Android-CA-MVI-boilerplate/blob/dev/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Config.kt).
For example, if I comment `implementation(project(":presentation"))` line in `mainscreen/build.gradle.kts`, the error disappears. Obviously, it isn't the solution.

**UPD: SOLVED**

Solution: you have to specify different package names in each `AndroidManifest.xml` files, i.e. `com.mycompany.example.launcher` for launcher module, `com.mycompany.example.presentation` for presentation module *et cetera*.

Answer (score 0):

[solution1]
You can delete the old version of gradle from your system and start installing its new version.

[solution2]
Or remove Android Studio and reinstall it